# Usando PHP para enviar uma resposta de um formulário para meu E-mail e está dando o erro 405 Not Allowed

Tags: php, html, html5

Toda vez que clico para enviar o formulário dá esse erro! Como posso resolver isso?

Código do Formulário em HTML 5 :

```
<form class = "col s12 m4 offset-m4 l4 offset-l4" action="submit_form.php" method="post">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix sKtq-scColor">&#xE87C;</i>
            <input id="icon_prefix" name="Nome" type="text" class="validate sKtq-scColor" required>
            <label for="icon_prefix" class = "sKtq-scColor">Nome</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix sKtq-scColor">&#xE0BE;</i>
            <input id="icon_prefix" name="Email" type="email" class="validate sKtq-scColor" required>
            <label for="icon_prefix" class = "sKtq-scCo lor">Email</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix sKtq-scColor">sort</i>
            <input id="icon_prefix" name="Assunto" type="text" class="validate sKtq-scColor" required>
            <label for="icon_prefix" class = "sKtq-scColor">Assunto</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix sKtq-scColor">chat_bubble</i>
             <textarea id="textarea1" name="Mensagem" class="materialize-textarea validate sKtq-scColor" required></textarea>
             <label for="textarea1" class = "sKtq-scColor">Mensagem</label>
        </div>

    </div>

    <br>

    <div class = "center-align">

        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light sKtq-bgScColor" type="submit"> Enviar
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>

    </div>

</form>
```

Código em PHP que está no arquivo `submit_form.php` :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "mtqr1@hotmailcom";
    $email_subject = "Mensagem do site";
    $name = $_POST['Nome']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['Email']; // required
    $subject = $_POST['Assunto']; // required
    $message = $_POST['Mensagem']; // required

    function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Name : ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email : ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Assunto : ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Mensagem : ".clean_string($message)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>
  <!-- include your own success html here -->

  <div class="feedback">Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</div>

  <?php
}
?>
```

Imagem do erro

[image: Erro]

Comment: Você está usando o Github pages? Se sim ele não permite rodar um script no lado servidor. O que levanta a questão: como você conseguiu colocar?

Comment: Então estou usando o Git Hub Pages e não encontrei em nenhuma parte da documentação dizendo que ele não permite isso eu simplesmente deixei esse script .php na raiz do meu projeto ! Você sabe o que está de errado com esse script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na documentação do github, mais especificamente em [What is GitHub Pages?](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/) fica claro que não dá para rodar um script PHP. Só é suportado documentos estaticos como html, css, e javascript.

A citação completa é essa:

> GitHub Pages is a static site hosting service and doesn't support
>   server-side code such as, PHP, Ruby, or Python.

Em português:

> O GitHub Pages é um serviço estático de hospedagem de sites e não
>   suporta código do lado do servidor, como PHP, Ruby ou Python.

Isso significa que quando você faz uma requisição POST, ela é bloqueada por padrão, retornando o error 405, já que foi definida nas configurações do servidor, uma vez que não há razão para permitir isso uma vez que são servidas apenas páginas estaticas.

Você até consegue acessar o arquivo usando uma requisição GET (é só dar um enter na url quando aparecer a mensagem de erro), mas será retornado o conteudo em texto plano do seu arquivo (nada vai ser interpretado).

Para conseguir rodar o seu script a algumas alternativas:

- Comprar uma hospedagem (para todo o site ou só para o script especifico)
- Ou usar uma hospedagem gratis só para o arquivo de enviar email (ai faz um link na pagina do github), embora as hospedagens gratis bloqueiem o envio de email.

Comment: Desculpa eu não tinha visto isso mas obrigado por avisar ! Então vou tentar achar uma forma de mandar um E-mail usando alguma API de Javascript ! Obrigado pela atenção ! Feliz Natal !